# Why is mpz_nextprime returning an even number (54)?

Tags: primes, gmp

I have to find out the first prime number grater then 4 using  library and I get 54 (q2 variable in the code). Any idea why? Could be the malfunction related to the 32 bit processor of the computer? I would be very grateful for your help!

Hereby the code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <gmpxx.h>

    using namespace std;

    void generate_Keys()
    {

    mpz_t q,q2;
    int rndBit;
    gmp_randstate_t gmpRandState2;


    mpz_init(q);
    mpz_init(q2);

    rndBit = 4;

    gmp_randinit_default(gmpRandState2);

    mpz_urandomb(q, gmpRandState2, rndBit);
    cout<<" q="<<q;//4

    mpz_nextprime(q2,q);
    cout<<" nextprime="<<q2;//54
    }

    int main()
    {
    generate_Keys();
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: it seems, like it prints 5 (the next prime number) and 4. And it's just looks like 54. Could you try to print a string got from the method `mpz_get_str ` rather than right to cout?

Comment: Don't forget to print a newline ('\n', `std::endl`, whatever) at the end. I cannot reproduce, it prints " q=4 nextprime=5" for me.

Comment: Thank you all, you were right, the programm works fine.